# Проблема с OpenGL: glBlendEquation, идентификатор не найден

Tags: opengl

Подключил все библиотеки, все работает (все рисуется, все движется). glBlendEquation() - пишет, что идентификатор не найден. Почему? Стоит последняя версии библиотеки openGL, даже пробовал поставить предыдущие. Спасайте, не могу понять в чем дело.)

Comment: Кто пишет, что идентификатор не найден? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он это пишет при компиляции или при линковке? По идее, glBlendEquation объявлена в glext.h

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine ~/tests/js $ fgrep -rn "glBlendEquation" /usr/include/GL          
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:3912:extern void APIENTRY glBlendEquation (GLenum);
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:4231:extern void APIENTRY glBlendEquationSeparate (GLenum, GLenum);
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:5580:extern void APIENTRY glBlendEquationEXT (GLenum);
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:7522:extern void APIENTRY glBlendEquationSeparateEXT (GLenum, GLenum);
```

Она же должна быть в составе основной библиотеки, она вполне стандартная

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine ~/tests/js $ fgrep glBlendEquation /usr/lib/libGL.so    
Двоичный файл /usr/lib/libGL.so совпадает
```

Однако, возможно это связано с происками мелкомягких. Возможно, стоит посмотреть сюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404776/how-to-compile-glblendequation-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: скачал glew, поставил теперь ошибка линковщика 
Ошибка 1 error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "__imp____glewBlendEquation" c:\Users\Стасик\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\gt\gt\gt.obj 
Ошибка 2 error LNK1120: 1 неразрешенных внешних элементов c:\users\стасик\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\gt\Debug\gt.exe

Comment: Вы выполнили всё как сказано на http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html  ?

Comment: @Стасик Коваленко Вместо уточняющего ответа нужно создавать комментарий: это соответствует формату форума.